# Garnet Cloisonne Effect Advice Needed

Tags: modeling

So, I'm working on a bit of concept work for a story project, and rather than drawing it I decided to model it in blender. It's going to be an Anglo-Saxon era sword with a garnet cloisonne pommel that will end up something like this:

[image]

So, as you can see there are shaped pieces of garnet set inside cells. Additionally, inside each cell is a piece of stamped foil. This foil is rotated at different angles, which affects how the light interacts with each cell. I'd like to replicate this effect in the model I'm working on, and plan to model the cells with a normal map at the bottom of each one, rotated in slightly different ways, for the stamped foil effect.

I'm running into two problems making that happen:

The first is keeping my shading smooth, and the second is maintaining the corners.

So, this is what my topology currently looks like:

[image]

The red line shows roughly where the cell walls will be. The mesh has a 1x SubSurf modifier applied. A mirror modifier is also being applied so I don't have to do the entire thing at once.

This is the mask I'll be using to cut the cells:

[image]

So clearly there's going to be issues with how the cuts affect the topology, which will contribute to problem #1.

There's also a matter of the corners, and keeping them properly sharp. ESPECIALLY that front left corner, which has a tendency to overlap from the subsurf, though in tests I've done in advance of doing the entire thing adding supporting loops can clear that up.

I'm of two minds how to proceed. One solution would be to add more edge loops before cutting. However in which case, why bother with the subsurf?

Which brings me to thought #2: Simply apply my subsurf to the mesh and add one at the same level to the mask BEFORE doing the knife project, which will give me those additional loops, anyway. Downside being now I have to work with a lot more polys at once.

Anyone have suggestions on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Suggestion: a retopo like approach. Draw the contours as a mesh snapping on the global surface mesh. (so don't start with a grid and knife).

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you're suggesting?

Comment: Just an example/quick test (won't have time to write an answer today), hope that help: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ZYlNQgSL/ Look at the modifier and snapping options to see the principles.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing there. The problem is that while the shading is preserved, it doesn't solve the other problem I'm dealing with of maintaining clean corners. While there are a few softer corners, there's also places that are a bit sharper.

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is I still need to have the cell floors, as well as the garnet surface. I suppose I can do the surface of the garnets as one piece using the mesh being used for the shrinkwrap, however that still doesn't give me the cell floors. And those I need to have as individual cells so I can set up the normal map for the foil at the bottom.

Comment: So, I've been playing with a variation of what you're doing. I applied by SubSurf modifier on the main part. I created the frame for my cells, added an applied the SubSurf modifier, an used Shrinkwrap to project it. I then applied the Shrinkwrap. When this was done, I took the parts of the surface that will be my garnets, made a hole for the cells to fit, and welded the vertices into the new topology. I now had the cell outlines in place, so extruded to create the walls of the cells and added bevels. So far so good. The problem is how to do the cell floors so I can apply the normal mapping.